# Want to reject first three lines also the dot(.) in each line using tcl/Tcl or Python

Tags: tcl

I want an output excluding the first three lines also the dot(.) at the end of the line.

I am using this code.

```
set content [split $content \n]
set content [lrange $content 2 end]
set content [join $content \n]
```

### Content - Input

```
{180319 arun S B} first set of chars. first chars.
{180316 yyay S B} second set of chars. second line.
{180314 ramaw S B} third line. third line. third line.
{180309 jfds S B} fouth line.
{180221 shrbsd S B} fifth line.fith line part 2.
{180214 shrbs S B} sixth line.
```

### Expected Output

```
{180309 jfds S B} fouth line
{180221 shrbsd S B} fifth line.fith line part 2
{180214 shrbs S B} sixth line
```

Comment: What do you mean by reject?

Comment: Exclude the first three lines.

Comment: What is the criterion for rejecting a line? Are we supposed to filter them because of numeric index or because of content?

Answer (score 1):

Using Tcl, I'd use a loop since you need to manipulate the individual lines:

```
set content [split $content \n]
set result [list]

for {set i 0} {$i <= [llength $content]} {incr i} {
    if {$i < 3} continue
    lappend result [regsub {\.$} [lindex $content $i] ""]
}

set result [join $result \n]
puts $result
```

[ideone demo](https://ideone.com/UuXhTV)

---

The equivalent in python:

```
import re

content = content.splitlines()
result = []

for i in range(0, len(content)):
    if i < 3:
        continue
    result.append(re.sub(r"\.$", "", content[i]))


print("\n".join(result))
```

[ideone demo](https://ideone.com/4deRYi)

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `lrange` with the right range, and [`regsub`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regsub.htm):

```
set content "{180319 arun S B} first set of chars. first chars.
{180316 yyay S B} second set of chars. second line.
{180314 ramaw S B} third line. third line. third line.
{180309 jfds S B} fouth line.
{180221 shrbsd S B} fifth line.fith line part 2.
{180214 shrbs S B} sixth line."

set content [join [lrange [split $content "\n"] 3 end] "\n"]
regsub -all -lineanchor {\.$} $content "" content
puts $content
```

The tricky bit is the `-lineanchor` option to `regsub`, which makes `$` match at spots right before newlines embedded in the string, and not just at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Another take, using [`lmap`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lmap.htm)

```
set result [lmap line [lrange [split $content \n] 3 end] {
    string trimright $line "."
}]
puts [join $result \n]
```